# Simple integral question

Tags: integration

I have trouble calculating $ \int _0 ^\pi cos^{2k} ( x/ 2) sin (x) dx$. Is it trivial that the answer is $ 2 \over k+1$? I have trouble figuring out why it is trivial. The book I am reading implies as if it is very trivial, because it just states this, and goes on.

Can one help me on this?

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
 I &= \int_0^\pi  {\cos ^{2k} \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)\sin x} dx 
\\
&= \int_0^\pi  {\cos ^{2k} \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)\left( {2\sin \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)\cos \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)} \right)dx}  \\ 
  &= 2\int_0^\pi  {\cos ^{2k + 1} \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)\sin \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)dx}  
\end{align}
Setting $u = \cos \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right) \Rightarrow du =  - \frac{1}{2}\sin \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)dx$
\begin{align}
 I = 2\int_1^0 {u^{2k + 1} \sin \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)\frac{{\left( { - 2} \right)dx}}{{\sin \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)}}}  = 4\int_0^1 {u^{2k + 1} dx}  = \frac{2}{{k +1}} \\ 
 \end{align}

Comment: You post highlighted the error in mine ;). +1

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
$$\sin x=2\sin\Bigl(\frac{x}{2}\Bigr)\cos\Bigl(\frac{x}{2}\Bigr)\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

${\displaystyle \cos^2\bigg({x \over 2}\bigg) = {1 + \cos(x) \over 2}}$, so the integral is the same as
$$\int_0^{\pi} \bigg({1 + \cos(x) \over 2}\bigg)^k \sin(x)\,dx$$
Substituting ${\displaystyle u = {1 + \cos(x) \over 2}}$, you have $\sin(x)\,dx = -2\, du$, so 
the integral becomes
$$-2\int_1^0 u^k \, du$$
$$= 2\int_0^1 u^k\,du$$
$$= {2 \over k + 1}$$